# ¿Por qué "okupación" y no "ocupación"?

Tags: coloquialismos, ortografía, letras

He visto [un titular](http://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/galicia/2017/04/21/dia-presenta-denuncia-okupacion-viviendas-galicia/0003_201704G21P10991.htm):

> Cada día se presenta una denuncia por **okupación** de viviendas en Galicia.

¿No debería escribirse con **c** en vez de con **k**?

Answer (score 9):

El DLE ya lo menciona:

> [**okupar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QySCSeP)
>   **De ocupar, con k, letra que refleja una voluntad de transgresión de las normas ortográficas.**
>   1. tr. jerg. Tomar una vivienda o un local deshabitados e instalarse en ellos sin el consentimiento de su propietario. Un centenar de personas okupó un edificio vacío. U. t. c. intr.

En general, la okupación es un acto de protesta hecha por colectivos especialmente beligerantes con la sociedad, etc. De ahí que se opte por infringir la regla de usar *c* en este caso y usar la *k*, del mismo modo que en muchas ocasiones se escribe *akí* o similares (si bien esto podría venir de la época en la que se enviaban mensajes de texto SMS y el límite de 140 caracteres obligaba a economizar donde se podía).

Fundéu habla de ello en [okupa, palabra correcta en español](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/okupa-palabra-correcta-en-espanol-819/):

> Debido a que el uso de okupa y de términos derivados —como okupar, okupación…— está ya muy asentado en países como España, la Argentina y Chile, no es necesario aplicarles ningún resalte, y así se recoge en la Ortografía de la Real Academia Española.

Nótese la diferencia con la acepción técnica típica:

> [**ocupar**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Qu5i3z8)
>   *Del lat. occupāre.*
>   1. tr. Tomar posesión o apoderarse de un territorio, de un lugar, de un edificio, etc., invadiéndolo o instalándose en él.

Quería ver cuándo entró en el diccionario, pero el Mapa de diccionarios hoy no funciona. Sin embargo, Fundéu dice en [El DRAE incluirá el término «okupa» en su próxima edición](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/el-drae-incluira-el-termino-okupa-en-su-proxima-edicion-779/):

> Estas palabras aparecerán en el DRAE precedidas por la marca «España», para explicar a los usuarios del diccionario que se trata de un uso propio del español de ese país.
>
> En España estos términos no necesitarán, por tanto, escribirse entre comillas o en cursiva, a diferencia de la mayoría de los países hispanos, donde al no ser utilizados habitualmente se seguirán escribiendo con comillas o en cursiva para destacar que no son de uso común.
>
> Okupa, okupar y okupación quedarán incluidas en la próxima edición del Diccionario de la lengua española, prevista para aproximadamente el año 2010, con el significado de ‘persona que se instala en una vivienda deshabitada sin consentimiento del propietario’ y de ‘tomar como propio, y sin consentimiento del dueño legal, una vivienda o local desocupados’.

Dado que la [primera edición del DLE después de 2010 fue el de 2014](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ediciones_DRAE_17-10-2014.pdf), podemos asumir que ese fue el año de inclusión. Eso sí, la palabra no lleva la marca «España».

Otros enlaces de interés de Fundéu al respecto de este uso *raro* de la *k*:

- [La esquina del idioma: «okupar» y «okupa»](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/la-esquina-del-idioma-okupar-y-okupa/)
- [HABLEMOS ESPAÑOL: SOBRE LA LETRA K](http://www.fundeu.es/noticia/hablemos-espanol-sobre-la-letra-k-4640/)

Comment: Te puedo confirmar que en la edición de 2001 del DLE (disponible en la propia web de la RAE) la palabra "okupar" no aparece registrada.

Comment: El primer artículo de Fundéu que mencionas ya indica que la palabra también es usual en Argentina y Chile, supongo que por eso no se le ha puesto ninguna marca de uso territorial.

Comment: @Gorpik sí, de hecho la noticia _El DRAE incluirá el término «okupa» en su próxima edición_ que menciona la marca «España» es de 2007 y luego el que mencionas _okupa, palabra correcta en español_ es de 2014, por lo que claramente estuvieron dando vueltas al tema. A ver si algún usuario de otros países de Hispanoamérica nos puede contar si lo usan en sus respectivos países también.